# CORS frustration

Tags: google-chrome, go, cors, vue.js

Have been digging this for few hours now.

I have vue.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#login',
    data: {
      logged_in: false,
      username: "",
      password: "",
      csrf_token: "",
    },
    methods: {
      login: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: apiEndpoint + '/login/', 
          type: "POST", 
          dataType: "json",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify({"username": username.value, 
          "password": password.value, 
          "csrf_token": this.csrf_token}), 
          success: (data) => {
            alert(1);
          }
        });
        return false;
      },
      getCsrfToken: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: apiEndpoint + '/login/', 
          success: (data) => {
            this.csrf_token = data["Csrf_Token"];

            if(data["User_id"] !== "") {
              this.logged_in = true;
            }
          }
        });   
      }
    }
  });

  vue.getCsrfToken();
});
```

And backend written in GO code:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")

fmt.Printf("METHOD - %s\n", r.Method)
if r.Method == "POST" {
```

My server handler:

```
appmux := http.NewServeMux()

appmux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../www/static"))))
appmux.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../www/assets"))))

appmux.Handle("/login/", commonMiddlewares(http.HandlerFunc(loginHandler)))
appmux.Handle("/logout/", secure(http.HandlerFunc(logoutHandler)))
```

The browser sends OPTIONS request witch is fine. Then it triest to send a POST request and gets 400, bad request but backend doesnt even register the request(fmt.Print..).

Why does my Post request gets 400?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: PICS!!

[image: stuff]

[image: stufff2]

Comment: Did you try this? `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", r.Header.Get("Origin"))`.

Comment: Tryed that just now, it doesnt even register the OPTIONS now. Really really confusing..

Comment: No, it does register. but without changes. the POST still returns 400 and doesnt register at the server( OPTIONS does register and return okey ).

Comment: In Go, what are you using to serve the app? `http.ServeMux` or some third party package like `gorilla/mux`? Also that handler that is setting those headers what path is it serving? `/` or `/login/` or something else?

Comment: updated the question with the server handler

Comment: P.S Disabling common mildwares does not do the trick.

Comment: Also, tryed to do the request from `postman`, it returns two empty lines. I am clueles...

Comment: P.S only happens on POST requests.

Comment: In your handler do you have any other code before the `w.Header.Set(...)` lines? besides 400, what's the error message that chrome prints to the console, and what's in chrome's network console? If possible screenshot the request response details from chrome's network tab, i.e. this tab http://commandlinefanatic.com/art034f011.png

Comment: Hey, i added both the options request and the post request pics.

I don't think i am adding any more Headers BEFORE that. However after that i am setting content type(but it doesnt get that far ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138255/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-ivrrimum).

Comment: Problem is still NOT solved!

Comment: @IvRRimUm you have double `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `*` with `127.0.0.1` and then accessing the server via `http://127.0.0.1`. I believe web browsers behave differently when given the wildcard (because they see it as a major security risk). Found initial [documentation supporting this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), but not definitive. I had this problem and I think this solved it.

Answer (score -1):

You should test your code against a test server like: https://www.posttestserver.com/, then you can go to http://posttestserver.com/data/ and view your request as sent because it may not be sending what you think it is.